# C++ List of Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

I have an array as follows: `uint64_t MyArray[500]`

I want to be able to `PUSH` and `POP` this array onto a stack / list of some sort.
 Basically I will be working with that array in a loop and need to `PUSH` the array onto a stack/list of some sort so I can POP it out later on in the loop... I will be `PUSHing` and `POPing` the array onto the stack/list multiple times, so the stack will grow and shrink along the way.

How do I work with a stack/list of arrays in C++ like this?  I don't want to simply declare a two dimensional array because I can't predict the size... would be much cleaner and robust if I could use some sort of "list of arrays" that I can `PUSH` and `POP` easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ has implemented a `stack` wrapper that may be useful. It is recommended that you work with `std::vector` however:

```
#include <stack and vector>

vector<uint64_t> v(500);
stack<vector<uint64_t>> sv;
sv.push(v);
sv.pop(v);
```

Comment: If he wants to preserve the original C array type he can just use pointers and use `stack<uint64_t*>` instead

Comment: If I use this approach, when I do sv.push(v) will it push a COPY of the vector onto the stack? I want to take a "snapshot" of the 'array'/vector and then keep working with it and push it onto the stack again later and somewhere in between will be pulling off the stack too (many times).

I don't want to push a pointer to the original instance (v in your example) because then when I keep working with v it will change ALL entries on the stack since they will all be a pointer to the same instance.

Comment: Yes you will be pushing a copy

Comment: I have learnt that the stack is LIFO... whereas I need FIFO. I found that a "Queue" will do this. Not sure how to work with it but I will try and work it out.

Comment: After everything I think I will go for something like this:

struct objMyArray {
    uint64_t MyArray[500]
};
 

Then I can use a queue like:

queue<objMyArray> MyArrayQueue;

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to juts create a `stack<uint64_t*>` values.

```
stack<uint64_t*> vector;
stack.push(MyArray);
stack.pop();
```

Note that this won't do anything to manage the memory of `MyArray`.  It will simply treat it as a pointer value.

Comment: I like the simplicity. If I created a new instance of `MyArray` which is a copy of itself, every time before pushing that copy to the vector, would that then take a "snapshot" of the data / manage the memory for me?

Comment: @TappaTappa assuming you copied the individual values, yes it would

Comment: @JaredPar... How would I manage the creation of a copy of the array...  it needs to be 'global' in scope... and I won't know how many copies I need to make along the way!

Comment: Because I need FIFO (I only just learnt that stack is LIFO), I will go for something like this: struct objMyArray { uint64_t MyArray[500] }; Then I can use a queue like: queue<objMyArray> MyArrayQueue;